# upload image from gallery using ImagePicker Library and set in ImageView with Glide library

Tags: android, android-studio

Get image from user gallery and camera using ImagePiker and set it in ImageView using Glide Library but when I did it shows nothing, my Android device has Android 10. I check some question but not complete my requirement

Here is code of ImagePicker

```
 ImagePicker.Builder builder = new ImagePicker.Builder(requireActivity());

    builder.allowMultipleImages(false);
    builder.allowOnlineImages(false);
    builder.compressLevel(ImagePicker.ComperesLevel.MEDIUM);
    builder.scale(500, 500);
    builder.directory(ImagePicker.Directory.DEFAULT);
    builder.extension(ImagePicker.Extension.PNG);
    builder.mode(ImagePicker.Mode.CAMERA_AND_GALLERY);

    builder.build();
```

and onActivityResult Method in Which i use Glide Library to set my image

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        if(requestCode == ImagePicker.IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE){
            List<String> paths = data.getStringArrayListExtra(ImagePicker.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH);

            if(paths != null){
                String imagePath = paths.get(0);
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+imagePath);
                // Load picked image
              //  setImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imagePath));
               Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).centerCrop().onlyRetrieveFromCache(true).dontAnimate().into(setImage);
          }}}}
```

Here is my XML code of ImageView

```
   <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addImages"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addHostel_iv"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addHostel_iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: internet permission is also added

Comment: Why are you talking about upload in the subject? I see no uploading.

Comment: i dont understand your answer?if not uploading kindly guide me about upload it.@blackapps

Comment: i am new so i dont know about it @blackapps

Comment: Where would you upload to? Thats what i dont understand.

Comment: i upload it on clicklistener using api in server

Comment: Can be. But is that relevant when your problem is that imageview stays blank? Your app can do so much things more.. you will not talk about them now .

Comment: when i click all imagepicker process is done ok but it dont show on my imageview that my problem why it dont show in my imageview

Comment: Yes i know your problem already from the beginning. 20 hours ago. And i wondered what it had to do with upload. I think nothing. But it is still in the subject of your post. Since 20 hours.